# Is "The end of evangelion" similar to what "Evangelion 4.0" is supposed to be?

Tags: evangelion

I just finished watching Evangelion 3.0, and since 4.0 is not out yet, I was wondering if just by watching "End of Evangelion" I can find out the end of the story... or if I have to watch the entire episodic version?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've yet to see Rebuild 3.0 but I would venture that it **probably won't**.

The reason being that the Rebuild series isn't just a retelling of the original story with new animation. While Rebuild 1.0 is basically the first six episodes of the original TV series with (much) better animation, Rebuild 2.0 departs quite a lot from the original, extensively reworking the character of Asuka, adding a new character, and changing some very pivotal events.

I would recommend seeing the original TV show and then watching End of Evangelion, or at least starting from episode 7. It should give you some historical context for the franchise and probably provide you with some interesting insights, specifically the infamous last two episodes.